# OutOfMemoryException thrown from BackgroundService

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have a `BackgroundService` running in an aspnetcore app on dotnet 7, running in docker on linux. The app is throwing OutOfMemoryExceptions every 9 hours or so, even though it's averaging 100MB memory usage with no spikes higher than 110MB, with 900MB available memory.

I suspect there's a memory fragmentation issue going on. It worked without any issues dotnet 6, the issues started right after moving to dotnet 7.

The background job is running every 30 seconds. Each iteration is doing an http request downloading about 2.5MB data and syncing the data to a database using EF Core 7. EF Core is throwing the OutOfMemoryExceptions when loading data from the database. There's about 3000 entities in total, and it's a batched process to minimize the amount of work EF has to do at once:

```
var locationDtos = await Get<List<LocationDto>>(); // 2.5MB of data.

const int batchSize = 50;

for (var batchStartIndex = 0; batchStartIndex < locationDtos.Count; batchStartIndex += batchSize)
{
    var locationDtosInBatch = locationDtos.Skip(batchStartIndex).Take(batchSize).ToList();
    var locationIdsInBatch = locationDtosInBatch.Select(x => x.LocationId).ToList();
            
    using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
    await using var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();

    var dbLocations = await dbContext.Locations
                                     .Where(x => locationIdsInBatch.Contains(x.ExternalId))
                                     .ToListAsync(); // Exception thrown here

    foreach (var locationDto in locationDtosInBatch)
    {
        var dbLocation = dbLocations.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ExternalId == locationDto.LocationId);

        if (dbLocation == null)
        {
            dbContext.Locations.Add(new Location
            {
                // 7 properties
                ExternalId = locationDto.LocationId,
                Name = locationDto.LocationName,
                TimeZone = locationDto.Zone
            });

            continue;
        }
                
        var dbEntity = dbLocations.Single(x => x.ExternalId == locationDto.LocationId);

        // 6 properties
        dbEntity.Name = locationDto.LocationName;
        dbEntity.TimeZone = locationDto.Zone;
    }

    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Each iteration should create a new instance of the service doing the syncing, since `LocationImportService` is registered as a scoped service: `services.AddScoped<LocationImportService>();`

```
public class LocationImportBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{ 
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public LocationImportBackgroundService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
        =>_scopeFactory = scopeFactory;

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using PeriodicTimer timer = new(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
        {
            using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
            await using var locationImport = scope.ServiceProvider
                                                  .GetRequiredService<LocationImportService>();
        
            await locationImport.Run(_scopeFactory, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

I've added the batching after issues started, hoping it would fix it. I've also tried to isolate the service doing the actual job as much as possible to make it easier to garbage collect, to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: By the way, since .NET6 we have had built-in batching so you can do `locationDtos.Chunk(batchSize)`

Comment: Also, maybe you should disable tracking in EF. For example: `dbContext.AsNoTracking().Locations.Where...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the way `HttpClient` was used, where a static instance was reused for each request. Rewriting to creating short-lived http clients using `IHttpClientFactory` fixed the issue.